# WPF MVVM DataGridColumnHeader DisplayName

Tags: wpf, data-binding, mvvm, datagrid, datagridcolumn

I got an DataGrid in MVVM which´s ItemsSource is bound to a Custom Model.

The properties in this model are named like their equivalent in the database.
For example this:

```
public string StapelStatus_Txt
    {
        get
        {
            return this.stapelstatusTxt;
        }
        set
        {
            this.stapelstatusTxt = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("StapelStatus_Txt");
        }
    }
```

Is it somehow possible (without renaming the propertie) to declare another displayname for the datagrid? I thought the data anotation "DisplayName" would help... but it don´t.

Someone got an idea?:)

Kind regards

Comment: return alternate name in get section

Comment: the get section does not return the columnheadername, but the value for the cell´s

Comment: How many DataGrids do you have? If not much then don`t autogenerate columns, declare them in XAML. Then you could customize them all you want.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can, for example, use [DisplayNameAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.displaynameattribute.aspx) on property and set column header like this:

```
<DataGrid AutoGeneratingColumn="OnAutoGeneratingColumn"/>

private void OnAutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
{
    e.Column.Header = ((PropertyDescriptor)e.PropertyDescriptor).DisplayName;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it could be

```
<DataGrid AutoGeneratingColumn="DataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn">

private void DataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
{
    e.Column.Header = MyPropertyNameConverter.Convert(e.PropertyName);
}
```